# In-memory MassTransit scheduled message

Tags: scheduling, masstransit, in-memory

I've used RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin for scheduling my message. it's worked without problem.

Now I want to configure in-memory MassTransit for scheduling messages at development environment.

My code in asp.net core:

```
Uri schedulerEndpoint = new Uri("queue:scheduler");
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.AddMessageScheduler(schedulerEndpoint);

        x.AddConsumer<ScheduleNotificationConsumer>();

        x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) => 
        {
            cfg.UseMessageScheduler(schedulerEndpoint);

            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        });
    });
```

Well, this code doesn't call my consumer after the specific time.

I read [this lin](http://%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/scheduling/)k and I guess I must use MassTransit.Quartz for in-memory scheduled messages, because , it said: the UseInMemoryScheduler method initializes Quartz.NET for standalone in-memory operation.

Is it correct?
if yes, but this link used the follow code, that has dependency to RabbitMq:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddMessageScheduler(new Uri("queue:scheduler"));

            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) => 
            {
                cfg.UseInMemoryScheduler("scheduler");

                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
        });
```

but I don't want to have any dependency to RabbitMq in development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the in-memory transport, you can use the new delayed scheduling that was [included in 7.1.8](https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.1.8.html#delayed-message-delivery-redelivery). This standardizes the configuration across all transports, and for the first time provides in-memory scheduling without Quartz.NET.

To configure the new delayed scheduler, use:

```csharp
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();

    x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) => 
    {
        cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this way with in-memory configuration. worked but has a problem; when calling SchedulePublish()  for example with 30 seconds (scheduled date time) into http request, then my main http request process waiting for 30 seconds!. With RabbitMQ configure didn't wait.

Comment: Yeah, that's an issue with 7.1.8, resolved in the next release.

Comment: I look forward to hearing from you